# Family Crowd to the travel.SE

Tags: discussion

From participating on this forum I am seeing that the crowd is primarily single (mostly backpackers) or a family with no kids travelers.  I think that adding more family related travel material would probably add to the sites popularity.

I mean travelling with kids doesn't have to start and end with Orlando and it's theme parks or other amusement parks.  Granted that kids are not much for the museums but there are other destinations people with kids can visit.

So how can we attract more of a family crowd here?

Comment: Good idea for a thematic week -- "Travelling with Kids"

Comment: have added as a chat room event day for the 29th of  Jan.  Users will be notified on the front page, or can register for the event (and others) at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule

Comment: I believe there are some travel questions on the [Parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) site, as well. And also, I loved planetariums and museums as a kid, but I also just love(d) to learn. :D

Comment: Looks like parenting is down. :(

Comment: Traveling with kids is just not "sexy" ;) There are more books on traveling with your dog, then about books about traveling with kids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fair, it is a site for "road warriors and seasoned travelers".  However, seasoned travellers can certainly have families!  Also traditionally it's 'easier' for families to book holidays through agents, leaving out the hard work of research online.

However, we have the occasional question about families, and I suspect we will get more as it becomes more mainstream:

- [How to book a bassinet for an infant on a flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1428/101)
- [Where to go in Morocco with toddlers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4983/101)
- [Preparing to take a 5 year old on the hike to Machu Picchu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4969/101) (which you yourself raised)
- [Travelling to Peru, Ecuador, Galapagos with kids](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4674/101) (which you yourself raised!)
- [Breast feeding in Iran](http://Breast%20feeding%20in%20Iran)
- [Are there hotels where children are not allowed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4326/101)
- [Travel with a child in Vietnam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2182/101)

so they do get asked, and as far as I can see, every single question tagged as [children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) has been answered at least once, which is positive.

One has to recognise that seasoned travellers and road warriors often are single - one doesn't *tend* to take kids to places like Congo, North Korea, or Bolivia.  Not that it can't be done, it's just rarer.

But as long as we continue to answer these questions promptly, helpfully and accurately, we may well find we start to get more traffic of this sort.  But it is important to realise that primarily, this site was not targeted at family travel when it started.

Comment: Speaking of [North Korea](http://fishmonger.ru/?idnews=119).  Wish someone had translated it into english. :)

Comment: As a father of twin toddlers, I kept on researching online and disliking the travel agencies. Researching gives some sense of independence and it is also part of the fun of traveling, but I am afraid that I agree with you on that having children drastically change your travel patterns

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd hope to do in the future.  I keep telling friends with kids that they can still travel, so I'll have to prove it one day ;)

Comment: Certainly I am already in the proving phase. Actually the only disadvantage is that you need to plan your accommodations more and traveling light is no longer an option. For the rest you can keep the travel virus alive. Falling in love with a "house-sparrow" is a better travel killer then kids! So be aware ;)

Answer (score 5):

I see this as a chicken-and-egg question. This isn't a Lonely Planet guide or Wikitravel that we can 'add' more questions for a certain demographic. Travel.SE will have more questions about family travel when we have more questions about family travel.

Comment: I am doing my best :) Will do a question later today, where I guess you will be one of the answer givers.