# Demographics on Travel.se

Tags: discussion

According to [this](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/family-crowd-to-the-travel-se) question, the typical travel.se visitor is single or family with no kids. Except for one specific [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/legalities-and-safety-concerns-of-visiting-prostitutes-in-amsterdam), where the singleness of the traveler in question was stated, I have not seen other indications of the typical marital status of a visitor.

Just out of curiosity can we draw a profile of a "typical" Travel.se visitor?

Comment: Apparently [toilet-challenged](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/ok-were-all-adults-here-so-really-how-on-earth-should-i-use-a-squat-toilet), [vodka-drinking](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-to-avoid-drinking-vodka), [shower-deprived](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5106/what-do-you-do-when-youre-on-the-road-and-you-cannot-shower) [naked-URL lovers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/591?m=2078840#2078840) with [weird eating preferences](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/where-can-i-eat-a-guinea-pig-in-ecuador). :-)

Comment: Apparently, that's one single guy ;)

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware of, aside from reading people's profiles.  You can get an idea quite often from the question.  I suspect you'll find that those looking at things to do near Orlando, say, are (stereo)typically families, while they're more likely to be young single / couples if travelling in Tajikistan.

Perhaps it's time for a survey? :)  I'm single, 31, male, from New Zealand, if that helps get the ball rolling.

Comment: I am 38, male with kids, from Belgium/Netherlands. I have been to Orlando for work and will travel to the Sahara with my kids soon, training my kids to be roadwarriors ;)

Comment: 27, male with 1 son, From Russia. Going to start travel with kid from this Summer. He'll be only 9 months old ^)

Comment: 26, male, Central Europe. u0m particularly traveling in Europe because I don't want to spend half of my money for a long haul flight ;)

Comment: 30, male with no kid, from Singapore/Indonesia. I have been to Malaysia and Europe.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind SE sites is that eventually a majority of the traffic is going to come from search engines. So in that sense, the demographics in our case too will depend on someone is searching online for would come across to our site.

Perhaps a better question would be what are the demographics of **repeat** visitors / top answerers. In that sense yes, I would reckon most here are solo backpackers.

Comment: +1 for pointing search engine being the main entry to the site.