# What are the opinions regarding a LinkedIn group on travel.SE?

Tags: discussion

To get idea on the [demographics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/demographics-on-travel-se) of frequent visitors to Travel.se, I have tried to search for fellow travelers on linkedin. So far I have only found Ankur and a ten fold of Marks. 
Apparently not a good search strategy. Anyone against creating a travel.se linkedIn group, people can join on free choice?

Comment: What's LinkedIn?

Comment: I don't see a problem if it's free to join. Kindly drop a link if you do create a group.

Comment: There is a [Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/118962814909394/), btw :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException LinkedIn is a kind of facebook for grown ups.

Comment: @MarkMayo But the group is not public. Hence not very useful, because you need a facebook account ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not in favour because of a suspicion that for most new registrants LinkedIn surreptitiously helps itself to their address book to bombard those addresses with advertising. It is already a nuisance that if ever I go to say a location in Booking.com in connection with a Q or A on Travel SE I then get a flood of e-mails offering discounts and special offers for that location.

Also, we have a means to contact one another where such contact may be welcomed by the recipient (ie our Profile details) and one of SE's strengths is its openness, whereas any group requiring joining would be bound to exclude at least some (or judging by chat which would seem to me to be an adequate alternative to a LinkedIn group, exclude almost all).

In any case, the question appears not to make any attempt to make a case for such a group, so seems to be mere idle inquisitiveness - the question linked to above even includes *Just out of curiosity*.